# Too much memory for a service/process

Tags: android, android-service

My app has a background service which periodically dowloads informations from the net.
According to MAT (memory analyzer) overall memory usage (retained) is in the order of KB, anyway if I open android's task manager I see 13-15 MB.
I don't know how it can be: main application is closed, no activities running, just the service!

Maybe it's because in the main activity I'm caching bitmaps with an LruCache? But, in theory, after exiting from this activity, memory should be freed up...

edit:
this is my LruCache code, not a big deal, just a singleton so that each activity share cache contents:

```
public class PortableCache {
private static final int CACHE_MB = 1;

private static LruCache<String, Bitmap> cachedBitmaps= new LruCache<String,Bitmap>(CACHE_MB*1024*1024){
    protected int sizeOf(String k,Bitmap v){
        return v.getRowBytes()*v.getHeight();
    }
};

public static LruCache<String, Bitmap> getImageCache(){
    return cachedBitmaps;
}

   }
```

but, with a cache size of 1MB, I don't think it is the main responsible...

edit2:
strangely enough as time passes service memory usage decreases...from 16MB now, after 1 hour, is 9 MB.

Comment: Post the code you are using that creates and manages teh LruCache

Comment: What version of Android OS are you running this on? Bitmap memory management is pretty buggy on Android < 3.0. Also, MAT will only tell you how much memory is used in the Dalvik heap, but not in the native heap. On Android 1.x and 2.x bitmap data is stored in the native heap. Also, I think you should be using `v.getByteCount()` instead of `v.getRowBytes()*v.getHeight()`